# Unity server instance barebone

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to start a unity server instance which loads minimal resources.  i.e loads only the meshes for collision detection all graphics are not rendered for optimization issues. Im currently getting 3% cpu utilization on a server which is not heavy on the gpu / cpu.

Answer (score 0):

running the instance with the -batchmode switch drops cpu usage to 0.5%